# Cannot disable the case auto-changing for network shared folder after upgrading to v1903 of Win 10

Tags: windows-10

I don't want to set whole Windows in case-sensitive, which means "Abc.TxT" & "abc.txt" are 2 files. I just want to disable the case auto-changing by Windows itself.

Before v1903, the names of network shared folder are kept its original letter case name by the switch,

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced] 
"DontPrettyPath"=dword:00000001
```

in registry.

But after v1903, the network shared folder will be auto changed to all lowercase name if its original name is full uppercase. This registry has no effect.

For Example,

> \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\000_IT

will be auto-changed to

> \\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\000_it

How to solve it?

OS Full Version (1903 Build 18362.267)

Answer (score 0):

How about use hostname (computer name) instead of ip address,

for example the hostname is "My-W10-PC",

1. use mix-case hostname.

   > \\My-W10-PC\
2. use all lowercase hostname.

   > \\my-w10-pc\
3. **DO NOT** use all uppercase hostname, per my test it will lead to all uppercase share name become all lower case.

   > \\MY-W10-PC\